# How can I search for all employees of several (a limited set of) employers

Tags: search, search-results

Can someone tell me how I can easily search for all employees of several employers, ideally using a single search string - i.e. something like:

employee of: 'employer A' OR 'employer B'? Ideally the results are displayed as a list from which I can select some or all for action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could tag the Employers, then search for them, but set 'display results as' (top right of Adv Search pre-4.6, bottom of first section in 4.6) to 'show as related contacts' which you would set to 'employees of'

Comment: This is the answer I would give, but just noting that "Display Results As" has moved in Civicrm 4.6, lower in the Advanced Search screen.